# How do I make python tkinter widgets appear on the right side of a frame and grow left?

Tags: python, tkinter

Current behavior, adding LabelFrame widgets (with their own label and picture children) into another Labelframe named "Test putting buffs..." The LabelFrame widgets are being added into the left side of the LabelFrame and "grow" to the right. Wanted behavior is for the widgets to appear on the right side of the frame and "grow" left.

Cannot seem to get there with anchor or sticky settings. How can this "grow-left" be done and still preserve the ability to sort by name or time remaining?

Current behavior gif:

[image: growing right]

Wanted behavior (mocked up with paint):

[image]

Code (took out the image stuff so files aren't needed to run):

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import time

class MainFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, container):
        super().__init__(container)

        self.grid(column=0, row=0)

        self.buffs_list_frames = []

        self.button1 = ttk.Button(self)
        self.button1['text'] = "Simulate frame list appended True Strike"
        self.button1['command'] = lambda: self.buffs_frame_list_is_appended(["True Strike", time.time() + 9])
        self.button1.grid(column=0, row=0)

        self.button2 = ttk.Button(self)
        self.button2['text'] = "Simulate frame list appended Bulls"
        self.button2['command'] = lambda: self.buffs_frame_list_is_appended(["Bulls", time.time() + 1080])
        self.button2.grid(column=0, row=1)

        self.button0 = ttk.Button(self)
        self.button0['text'] = "Simulate frame list appended Endurance"
        self.button0['command'] = lambda: self.buffs_frame_list_is_appended(["Endurance", time.time() + 1080])
        self.button0.grid(column=0, row=2)

        self.button3 = ttk.Button(self)
        self.button3['text'] = "Simulate frame list put into .grid() and displayed"
        self.button3['command'] = lambda: self.buffs_display_nicely()
        self.button3.grid(column=0, row=3)

        self.button4 = ttk.Button(self)
        self.button4['text'] = "START loops of time passing"
        self.button4['command'] = lambda: self.buffs_loop_time_passing()
        self.button4.grid(column=0, row=4)

        self.test_label_frame = ttk.LabelFrame(self, text="Testing putting buffs into a frame with grid")
        self.test_label_frame.grid(column=1, row=0)


    def buffs_loop_time_passing(self):
        for x in self.buffs_list_frames:
            x.buff_timer.set(f"{x.buff_birthday - time.time():.1f}s")
            if x.buff_birthday < time.time() + 6:
                x['background'] = 'red'
            if x.buff_birthday < time.time():
                self.buffs_list_frames.remove(x)
                x.destroy()
        self.after(1000, self.buffs_loop_time_passing)

    def buffs_frame_list_is_appended(self, added_buff):
        """ makes the buff frame and adds to the list of frame widgets
        """ 

        self.buff_frame = tk.LabelFrame(self.test_label_frame, borderwidth=1, text=added_buff[0][0:4], labelanchor="n") 

        # self.buff_frame.buff_image_reference = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(added_buff[2]))
        # self.buff_frame.buff_image_label = ttk.Label(self.buff_frame, image=self.buff_frame.buff_image_reference)
        # self.buff_frame.buff_image_label.image_keep = self.buff_frame.buff_image_reference
        # self.buff_frame.buff_image_label.grid(column=0, row=0)
        self.buff_frame.buff_birthday = added_buff[1]
        self.buff_frame.buff_timer = tk.StringVar()
        self.buff_frame.buff_timer.set(f"{self.buff_frame.buff_birthday - time.time():.1f}s")
        self.buff_frame.buff_label = ttk.Label(self.buff_frame, textvariable=self.buff_frame.buff_timer)
        self.buff_frame.buff_label.grid(column=0, row=1)
        self.buffs_list_frames.append(self.buff_frame)

        self.buffs_display_nicely()

    def buffs_display_nicely(self):
        """ takes the list of frames, sorts by name, and .grids()s them into the test frame
        """
        self.buffs_list_frames = sorted(self.buffs_list_frames, key=lambda z: z['text'])
        print(f"sorted? {self.buffs_list_frames}")
        j = 0
        for x in self.buffs_list_frames:
            x.grid(row=0, column=j)
            j += 1

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # configure the root window
        self.title('NWN Buff Watcher')
        self.geometry('300x50')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    main_frame = MainFrame(app)
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Try using `x.pack(side="right")` instead of `x.grid(row=0, column=j)` inside `buffs_display_nicely()` function.

Comment: @acw1668 that works! However, it loses the sorting I'm doing just above... so the buffs aren't alphabetical anymore, just the order they're added in. Any way to pack right in grid or preserve the order somehow?

Comment: Can you sort in reverse order?

Comment: @acw1668 yes, added this quick:

for x in self.buffs_list_frames[::-1]:

however, nothing changes because the sorting was all through the grid columns. Moving to pack() takes away what I was using to sort the labelframes.

Additional note, I did try to reverse sort in the grid. That just made them grow from the left in reverse alphabetical order.

Comment: I only see you sort the items in alphabetical order inside the function.  So I expected to sort the items in revese alphabetical order is ok after changing to `pack()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (using @acw1668's suggestion):

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import time

class MainFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, container):
        super().__init__(container)

        self.buffs_list_frames = []
        self.buttons_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.buttons_frame.pack(fill="both", side="left")

        self.button1 = ttk.Button(self.buttons_frame, text="Simulate frame list appended True Strike",
                                  command=lambda: self.buffs_frame_list_is_appended("True Strike", 9))
        self.button1.grid(column=0, row=0)

        self.button2 = ttk.Button(self.buttons_frame, text="Simulate frame list appended Bulls",
                                  command=lambda: self.buffs_frame_list_is_appended("Bulls", 1080))
        self.button2.grid(column=0, row=1)

        self.button0 = ttk.Button(self.buttons_frame, text="Simulate frame list appended Endurance",
                                  command=lambda: self.buffs_frame_list_is_appended("Endurance", 1080))
        self.button0.grid(column=0, row=2)

        #self.button3 = ttk.Button(self.buttons_frame, text="Order items", command=self.order_items)
        #self.button3.grid(column=0, row=3)

        self.button4 = ttk.Button(self.buttons_frame, text="START loops of time passing",
                                  command=self.buffs_loop_time_passing)
        self.button4.grid(column=0, row=4)

        self.test_label_frame = ttk.LabelFrame(self, text="Testing putting buffs into a frame with grid")
        self.test_label_frame.pack(side="right")

    def buffs_loop_time_passing(self):
        for x in self.buffs_list_frames:
            x.buff_timer.set(f"{x.buff_birthday - time.time():.1f}s")
            time_now = time.time()
            if x.buff_birthday < time_now + 6:
                x.config(bg="red")
            if x.buff_birthday < time_now:
                self.buffs_list_frames.remove(x)
                x.destroy()
        self.after(100, self.buffs_loop_time_passing)

    def buffs_frame_list_is_appended(self, added_buff, time_alive):
        """ makes the buff frame and adds to the list of frame widgets
        """ 
        buff_frame = tk.LabelFrame(self.test_label_frame, borderwidth=1,
                                   text=added_buff[:4], labelanchor="n") 

        # buff_frame.buff_image_reference = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(added_buff[2]), master=self)
        # buff_frame.buff_image_label = ttk.Label(buff_frame, image=buff_frame.buff_image_reference)
        # buff_frame.buff_image_label.image_keep = buff_frame.buff_image_reference
        # buff_frame.buff_image_label.grid(column=0, row=0)
        buff_frame.buff_birthday = time.time() + time_alive
        buff_frame.buff_timer = tk.StringVar(master=self)
        buff_frame.buff_timer.set(f"{buff_frame.buff_birthday - time.time():.1f}s")
        buff_frame.buff_label = ttk.Label(buff_frame,
                                          textvariable=buff_frame.buff_timer)
        buff_frame.buff_label.grid(column=0, row=1)
        self.buffs_list_frames.append(buff_frame)

        self.order_items()

    def order_items(self):
        self.buffs_list_frames = sorted(self.buffs_list_frames, key=lambda z: z['text'], reverse=True)
        for x in self.buffs_list_frames:
            x.pack_forget()
            x.pack(side="right")


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # configure the root window
        self.title("NWN Buff Watcher")
        # self.geometry("300x50")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    main_frame = MainFrame(app)
    main_frame.pack()
    app.mainloop()
```

I made a few changes to your code. The main thing is that I removed `buffs_display_nicely` and instead added `buff_frame.pack(side="right")`. The `side="right"` tells `tkinter` to add the widgets from the right to the left.

Also you can improve your code by a lot if you add a class instead of using `buff_frame.buff_birthday`, `buff_frame.buff_timer`, ... Also it will make your life a lot easier

Comment: Thank you, pack(side='right') does work to have the widgets appear on the right, but then I lose the ability to sort the buffs that I used in "buffs_display_nicely".

Is there any way to preserve the ability to sort the labelframe "buff" widgets that are displayed? Also, if you have any input on how to make a class for the birthday and timer I'm open to guidance... I am just starting out landed on adding them as attributes just to keep everything in one object. I don't know if that helps performance or anything, for example, when they're destroyed.

Comment: @Mattamue How do you want to sort them?

Comment: in the example code I was sorting by name, but I'd like to also be able to sort them by remaining time.

Comment: @Mattamue By name shouldn't be hard but by time will take a long time to implement. I will delete my answer and I will try to find a solution.

Comment: @Mattamue I think I fixed the issue. Can you please try it again?

Comment: Hey works great! The forget seems to re-set the widget and then when the full list is passed back through its organized. Perfect. Slight modification, I added the [::-1] back in to get the alphabetical back to go from right to left, but it's perfect.

Comment: @Mattamue Ooops. I will add that to my answer :D. Did you know that the `sorted` function also takes in a `reverse` parameter that you can set to `True`? It should actually run faster

Comment: Yes I'd read that reverse works too, but I heard the opposite that [::-1] is faster! I'm just glad it works now.

Comment: @Mattamue Just tested it. `sorted(..., reverse=True)` is 4.88% faster. When using `[::-1]` python has to build a sorted list then a reversed list. Unlike with `sorted(..., reverse=True)` where it only needs to create 1 list. That is why it is a bit faster. The change is unnoticeable so use the approach you are more comfortable with.